# Changing <!DOCTYPE> to <!DOCTYPE html> causes my wrapper to not extend

Tags: html, css, doctype

I just checked my personal landing page on the W3C Validator to make sure it was correct HTML5, and found out I needed to have `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of `<!DOCTYPE>` to pass.

However the background image won't extend to the bottom. 
I've tried min-heights for the wrapper, and clears, but nothing seems to work.

Normal: http://gbhall.com/

`<!DOCTYPE html>`: http://gbhall.com/index2.php

**Edit: You'll no longer be able to see the error as I've updated it to the solution provided below.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your body and html 100% height also:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me in a quick edit using Firebug. 

Aljullu did solve it below by adding `position: absolute` to the wrapper.

Comment: setting `html,body{height:100%}` and `#wrapper{height:100%}` should fix it while keeping the wrapper in normal flow.

Comment: Oh wait that does work. This seems more elegant, I've changed my accepted answer to this. 

Thank you to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing:

```
position: absolute
```

In your `wrapper` class.

Comment: Ah you beauty!

That works, thank you!

Why does adding an absolute position cause it to extend?

Comment: And any clue why the correct DOCTYPE to HTML5 caused it to be parsed differently?

Comment: It makes the browser render your page in standards mode, which is the entire point of requiring a proper doctype.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on that? For it to be standards compliant does a wrapper need to specify its position?

Comment: @gbhall watch out while you're using that technique. `$('body').height()` will always be `0` unless you explicitly specify it, and it will not grow with your wrapper.

Comment: Oh damn, do you have an alternative solution?